# ArcGIS Pro .pdf export - Colors are wrong

Tags: arcgis-pro, export, pdf, color

I am exporting a .pdf map from ArcGIS Pro (2.5) and the coloring is coming out completely different when I open it in in Adobe Acrobat. (Pictures below)[image: Pro Export][image: Opened in Adobe Acrobat]

It seems like this is only a problem on my machine, as others can open the .pdf and the colors render correctly.There is no rasterization, all exported layers are vectors. Any ideas on what could be causing this?